# Allocate more than 2 GB of dma common buffer

Tags: memory-management, buffer, driver, wdk, pci-e

I am developing a driver for PCI Express in Windows environment.
I use Windows7 and Windows10 and the HW is i7-7700K, RAM: 16GBytes.

There is no problem in using up to 2GBytes buffer allocated so far.
But, more than 2GB is not allocated.

Here is the code snippet  that succeeded in allocating 2GB dma common buffer.

DEVICE_DESCRIPTION dd;

RtlZeroMemory(&dd, sizeof(dd));

dd.Version = DEVICE_DESCRIPTION_VERSION;

dd.InterfaceType = InterfaceTypeUndefined;

dd.MaximumLength = 0x200000; // 2MB DMA transfer size at a time

dd.Dma32BitAddresses = FALSE;

dd.Dma64BitAddresses = TRUE;

dd.Master = TRUE;

pdx->AdapterObject = IoGetDmaAdapter(pdx->Pdo, &dd, &nMapRegisters);

pdx->vaCommonBuffer = (*pdx->AdapterObject->DmaOperations->AllocateCommonBuffer)
(pdx->AdapterObject, 0x80000000, &pdx->paCommonBuffer, FALSE);

What is the size limit for the DMA common buffer allocation and why?

If we changing length 0x80000000 (2GB) to 0xC0000000 (3GB) above causes the buffer allocation to fail.
How can I allocate up to 4GB and more than 4GB dma common buffer using AllocateCommonBuffer()?

Thank you very much for your valuable time and comments in advance.

Respectfully,
KJ

Answer (score 0):

I believe that DMAv2 (which is the best Windows 7 supports) cannot do more than 4GB in a single allocation, so there **is** a hard limit.

But even before you hit the hard limit, you're going to start seeing nondeterministic allocation failures, because AllocateCommonBuffer gives you **physically contiguous pages**.

As a thought experiment: all it takes is 8 unmovable pages placed at pathologically-inconvenient locations before you can't find 2GB of contiguous pages out of 16GB of RAM. And a real system will have a lot more than 8 unmovable pages, although hopefully they aren't placed at such unfortunate intervals.

Compounding matters, DMAv2 refuses to allocate memory that straddles a 4GB boundary (for historical reasons). So of the 3,670,017 different pages that this allocation *could* start at, 50% of them are not even considered. At 3GB, 75% of possible allocations are not considered.

We've put a lot of work into the DMA subsystem over the years: DMAv3 is a more powerful API, with fewer weird quirks. Its implementation in Windows 10 and later has some fragmentation-resistance features, and the kernel's memory manager is better at moving pages. That doesn't eliminate the fundamental problem of fragmentation; but it does make it statistically less likely.

Very recent versions of the OS can actually take advantage of the IOMMU (if available and enabled) to further mitigate the problem: you don't need the physical pages to be contiguous anymore, if we can just use the IOMMU to make them *seem* contiguous to the device. (An MMU is exactly why usermode apps don't need to worry about physical memory fragmentation when they allocate massive buffers via `malloc`).

At the end of the day, though, you simply can't assume that the system has any 2 contiguous pages of memory for your device, especially if you need your device to operate on a wide variety of systems. I've seen production systems with oodles of RAM routinely fail to allocate 64KB of common buffer, which is "merely" 16 contiguous pages. You will need to either:

- Fall back to using many, smaller allocations. They won't be contiguous between them, but you'll be more successful at allocating them.
- Fall back to a smaller buffer. For example, in on my home turf of networking, a NIC can use a variety of buffer sizes, and the only visible effect of a smaller buffer might just be degraded throughput.
- Ask the user to reboot the device (which is a **very** blunt way to defragment memory!).
- Try to allocate memory once, early in boot, (before memory is fragmented), and never let go of it.
- Update the OS, update to DMAv3 API, and ensure you have an IOMMU.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your answer helped me a lot to understand the problem. I changed it as below and tested it and I got the desired result. However, I want to make sure this is the correct way to do it and make sure it works well in the future.dd.ScatterGather = TRUE;
dd.Dma32BitAddresses = TRUE;
dd.Dma64BitAddresses = TRUE;
I can get allocated common buffers up to 10GBytes(total).
In other words: If I changing length 0x80000000 (2GB) to 0x20000000 (512MB), I can get about 20 buffers. If I changing length 0x80000000 (2GB) to 0x200000 (2MB), I can get around 5000 buffers.

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right.

Comment: I don't understand the address of the allocated buffer.
In the 64-bit setting test, I get the physical address(pdx->paCommonBuffer) is distributed within the [0 ~ 0x4 FFFF FFFF] range.
Although the 64-bit area is 0 ~ 0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF, the RAM is actually 16GByte.
Therefore, it is thought that it should be within the range of 0 ~ 0x3 FFFF FFFF, but there are some value beyond this range.
Isn't the starting physical address of 16GB RAM not 0?

Comment: Some address ranges are used for memory-mapped IO and other special firmware uses. https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/system-address-map-initialization-in-x86x64-architecture-part-1-pci-based-systems/